# How to use group by in a case where key values are stored in single cell using commas

Tags: mysql, sql, database, aggregate

I have a case where I have a table event. The event may be of various categories(many) as defined in categories table. The event table contains a column category where the ids of categories that the event belongs to is stored in a single varchar field separated by commas. eg. 2,5,18. In such a case can I/ if yes how do I use a group by case. I need to count the events on the basis of categories. But no unique key field has been defined for categories. 
eg category table

```
id   categoryname

1     music

2     dance

3     some other
```

event table

```
id   eventname         category

1     dance plus        1,2

2     xyz got talent    1,3
```

Im expecting to count number of events on basis of categories and expect a result as:

```
count    category

2         music

1         dance

1         some other
```

Comment: Post sample input and expected output.

Comment: First try splitting your values `2,5,18`, .... to multiple rows. Then apply count function to those rows. Anyway, could you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach   I did it please have a look

Comment: @SalmanA  pleae have a look now

Comment: Is there any reason for storing the data this way? Using a normalized table structure, you keep many problems away

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm working upon this table structure whose design I have no control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just events with categories table using [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT categories.id, categories.categoryname, COUNT(*)
FROM categories
JOIN events ON FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, events.category) > 0
GROUP BY categories.id, categories.categoryname
```

And if you want to include categories with 0 events:

```
SELECT categories.id, categories.categoryname, COUNT(events.id)
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN events ON FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, events.category) > 0
GROUP BY categories.id, categories.categoryname
```